# Check if TinyMCE 4.x is in Fullscreen Mode

Tags: tinymce

Is there a way to check if TinyMCE is in fullscreen mode?

I would like to press 'Esc' to exit full screen mode butI also use 'Esc' to cancel editing. Hence I would like a way to first check if the editor is in fullscereen mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When TinyMCE is in Fullscreen Mode "mce-fullscreen" class is appended to body tag.

So all you need to do is check for the existence of mce-fullscreen class.

```
if $('.mce-fullscreen').length{

// Do something here,the editor is in fullscreen mode

}
```

Answer (score 9):

The [fullscreen plugin](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/plugins/fullscreen/plugin.js#L88) fires an event, when its state changes:

```
  var tinyOptions = {
      plugins: [ 'fullscreen' ],
      setup: function(editor) {
          editor.on('FullscreenStateChanged', function(e) {
              console.log('FullscreenStateChanged event', e);
          });
      }
  };
```

This way you can track the state yourself.

Comment: And to take it even further, the event object returned includes the state changed to: `e.state` will be `true` if entering fullscreen mode, and `false` if no longer in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the editor object:

`editor.plugins.fullscreen.isFullscreen();`

Comment: How to access the object?

Answer (score 1):

This way is quick and simple.

```
    var catchFulscreen = function() {

    if( $('.mce-fullscreen').length > 1){

        console.log('Now the editor is on fullscreen mode');
    }

}

setInterval(catchFulscreen, 100);
```

This code was tested on TinyMce 4.1.x

But I had wanted to know to access inited TinyMce Object. If the object can be access, much more better solution for catching fullscreen mode as event!